# Where can I share great resources I come across?

Tags: support

Say I am studying a particular topic (CS theory) for my work/otherwise and I come across a great resource on the topic. Is this site a good place to share the resource (link/ppt/pdf), or maybe you can recommend some other site ?

Comment: If encounter many of these, start a blog/tumblr/whateverishipnow?

Comment: @Raphael Never came across tumblr. will explore it now. I do have a blog on wordpress, and I have been posting content from quite some time, but I feel that it does not reach as many people as it can reach on this platform. Offcourse, I am not 100% sure. So, I need to experiment.

Comment: I do wish there was some better informal form of communication to the *.SE community. Meta is still Q&A/formal, chat is not good enough; few people would read back into the buffer. I would love a reddit-like message board, where people can simply post links of interest; I am at a loss to communicate to people who I am friendly with on cs.SE about things I think they would be interested in, but is not a question, or answer, or anything about a question or answer, just cs-related. (continued)

Comment: (continued) Something I would share on /r/compsci for example. Example, if I made a cs-related tool, I would to get the community's attention. I wish SE would implement something very simple that would allow this.

Comment: there are a lot of google groups in various areas now, try searching them. also try se chat rooms. re realz' comments, wonder if new reddit communities can be started? see also "social bookmarking"....

Comment: @vzn but I feel like there is no way to communicate these things with *this* community. Ironically, any solution like "start another community <there>" suffers the same problem: there is no place to publicize that new community, and no one in this community will know about it.

Comment: @realz agreed! se sites have their own concept of how a "community" functions within a particular framework which is at times constricting. it is not nec focused on building communities, that is a peripheral aspect of the Q/A type format.... idea: suggest asking a question in main or meta that youd like to see addressed that you yourself answer.... for example "girldegit" has said she's interested in autocomplete & could answer her own question or add comments to her question on it....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site (and the Stack Exchange network in general) is a [questions and answers site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/about). Questions generally fit the mold of ”I have a problem, how do I solve it?“. The problem type can be varied — “how do I make my car start?”, “how do I prove this theorem?”, “how can I understand this text?”, etc. But sharing resources doesn't fit. Stack Exchange is not a link collection — we greatly frown on answers that just say ”go read this other document“, we expect answers to have actual content. So sharing a resource via a question and answer pair would only be appropriate is that resource solves a problem and the answer explains the solution — for example, “how do I prove this theorem?” → “here's a summary of the proof published in <article>: …”

You can post pretty much anything in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) as long as it's related to the site's topic and generally appropriate¹. Just don't overdo it — chat isn't a place for spamming.

There are sites on the web that are dedicated to links to resources or have designated areas for that. [Reddit](http://reddit.com/) comes to mind: [Computer Science: Theory and Application](http://www.reddit.com/r/compsci), [Algorithms](http://www.reddit.com/r/algorithms), [CS education](http://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions), [CS career questions](http://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions), … [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/) is another (at least for sufficiently applied topics).

¹  <sub>For example, illustrating a compression algorithm with an X-rated picture would not be appropriate.</sub>

Comment: That said, there is also the [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) paradigm. So, *if* you can formulate an SE-good question (in particular, focused enough to be helpful and searchable in specific problem cases while being broad enough to apply to lot of cases) and *if* you can formulate a good answer (see Gilles' answer) that builds on and references the material you found, then it is fair to do so.

Comment: @Raphael. What I understood is that if I come across a great resource while searching for an answer, I can post the question which brought me to that link, on SO/SE, and then answer my own question, the content of which can build upon the link's content I wanted to share (I can also cite that link as reference). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @girlDevelopIt Don't post a question-answer pair just to share a link. Post a question-answer pair to share a solution to a problem — which happens to contain the link as an attribution to the inventor of the solution or as a place to find more background information.

Comment: imho the whole "ask a question that you answer" while encouraged by some is not really a very common use of stackexchange & is not really rewarded with voting patterns typically....

Answer (score 1):

a great option around here (the stackexchange world) is a relatively newly introduced [community blog](http://stackexchange.com/blogs) system on stackexchange. it looks like about 21 se sites/communities are blogging. more info on starting [here](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/). the sites may work on a somewhat volunteer system to create blogs. of course you can always start your own blog too. another option is "guest blogging" on someone elses site. some people on here [incl mods] have their own blogs.

also the [CS chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science) has been active over the last few weeks. its also easy to start your own public chat room and post to it regularly if you have material over an extended time. the pages are public and URL/web page accessable.

Comment: mmm why don't we have a community blog

Comment: @RealzSlaw All it takes to have a community blog is people to write the posts. It's better if there's someone who coordinates things and prods people into writing.

Comment: @Gilles prod away :P

Comment: @RealzSlaw I was hinting that you should take that job. I won't do it. It really doesn't suit my personality. Feel free to call on me for other tasks such as proofreading and managing access rights.